# JPA like-query, accounting for locale

Tags: jpa, locale, criteria-api

I am constructing a JPA search query using the `CriteraBuilder` and must account for different locales. The query must also be case-insensitive.

On the Java side it's relatively straightforward to account for locale:

```
"%" + queryString.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT) + "%"
```

However, the `CriteriaBuilder.upper()` function does not acconut for Locale as far as I can tell. Is there another way to ensure that locale is handled?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to a String like this

```
query.where(builder.like(builder.upper(root.get(TestEntity_.locale).as(String.class)), "%DE%"));
```

Important is

```
root.get(TestEntity_.locale).as(String.class)
```

Comment: That's not quite what I meant, I'm not trying to match the locale in the entity, I'm trying to match another String attribute while taking into account the locale (e.g. capital i in Turkish is different)

Comment: I do not really understand, what you want to do. Can you change your example so that I can see how you want to use the `CriteriaBuilder` with the Turkish 'i' and the `upper` or `uppercase` function . In your example Locale.ROOT means ''. That's why the example is not very helpful